# What are the interior trims along windshield?

Tags: interior, trim

Hey I’m trying to buy the trim that is on the left
And right of windshields.  I don’t know the name.
 It’s on the inside and forms from the dash to the roof of the vehicle.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing the 'A' Pillar internal trim.

Comment: @HandyHowie sounds like a winner

Comment: Does [this answer help](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/24856/4152)?