# How to tell what mark is my golf?

Tags: vw, golf, vehicle-identification

So I bought my first car a VW Golf

**Model Variant GOLF**

**Model Description 1.6 TDI 105 S 5dr**

**Year Of Manufacture   2013**

**Registration Date 02/12/2013**

I would like to know what Mark Golf it is, is it mk6 or mk7

[image: VW Golf]

Answer (score 1):

The year of manufacture denotes which "Mk" it is.

- Mk6 2008-2013 Europe
- Mk6 2010-2014 (in North America)
- Mk7 2013-2020 Europe
- Mk7 2015-2021 (in North America)

**EDIT:** After some further digging, I realized the Mk6 & 7 were a little strange in that those in North America spanned different years then those in Europe.

As for a tell tale between the two, you need only to look at the hood (bonnet). The Mk6's hood has a rounded and smooth line from the [A-pillar](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/24852/4152) to the front, where as the Mk7's hood has a sharp line.

So, that would mean my first guess was wrong on your Golf as it is a Mk7. Strange world we live in.

Comment: @Kristaps - See edits. I need to ensure i'm looking outside the States when I answer :o)